# Need to understand celery crontab

Tags: python, cron, celery, scheduled-tasks, django-crontab

I am running a cron job using **celery.schedules crontab** library which looks like this

```
'task-hourly': {
        'task': 'task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='*/1'),
        'options': {
            'queue': 'celery-periodic-queue'
        }
}
```

Now this job is running every minute, and in the crontab document, it is written,
`.. attribute:: hour

```
    - A (list of) integers from 0-23 that represent the hours of
      a day of when execution should occur; or
    - A string representing a Crontab pattern.  This may get pretty
      advanced, like ``hour='*/3'`` (for every three hours) or
      ``hour='0,8-17/2'`` (at midnight, and every two hours during
      office hours).
```

**hour='*/3' (for every three hours)**

So, my understanding is that it should run every hour.
Then, I did some research and somewhere I read that this crontab format means, that this job will run every hour every minute, which left me highly confused.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, it should run every hour.

You can try to specify the minutes to be sure `(minute=0, hour='*/1')`

It should default to this, but just see what happens when you explicitly put it in there.

Otherwise the problem might be from somewhere else.